# Average of marks for three topics

Tags: python, dictionary, average

I am trying to create a program that will ask the user for a username and password. If the login details are correct, the program should ask for the students name and then ask for three scores, one for each topic. The program should ask the user if they wish to enter another students details. The program should output the average score for each topic. I cannot work out how to enter the student marks for each topic per student and also how to work out the average for each topic for the class.

Can you please help?

```
login="teacher"
password="school"

usrnm=input("Please enter your username: ")
pw=input("Please enter your password: ")

if (usrnm==login) and (pw==password):
  print("==Welcome to the Mathematics Score Entry Program==")
  print("Do you want to enter the students score? Yes/No: ")
  option = input()
  option = option.title()
  student_info = {}
  student_data = ['Topic 1 : ', 'Topic 2 : ', 'Topic 3 : ']
  while (option != "No"):
    student_name = input("Name: ")
    student_info[student_name] = {}
    score1 = int(input("Please enter the score for topic 1: "))
    student_info[student_name][Topic_1] = score1
    score2 = int(input("Please enter  the score for topic 2: "))
    student_info[student_name][Topic_2] = score2
    score3 = int(input("Please enter  the score for topic 3: "))
    student_info[student_name][Topic_3] = score3
    print("Do you want to enter the students score? Yes/No: ")
    option = input()
    option = option.title()
  average = sum(student_info.values())/len(student_info)
  average = round(average,2)
  print ("The average score is ", average)
else:
  print("Access denied!")
```

Comment: do you need to track the average score by topic, or scores for each student?

Comment: output the average score for each topic (three topics).

Comment: topic_one_scores = [score[0] for student in student_info]
    average_topic_one = sum(topic_one_scores)/len(topic_one_scores)                                       this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

just keep the marks seperate from the student names

```
students = []
marks = []
option = ""
while (option != "No"):
    students.append(input("Name"))
    marks.append([float(input("Mark_Category1:")),
                  float(input("Mark_Category2:")),
                  float(input("Mark_Category3:"))])
    option = input("Add Another?")

import numpy
print(numpy.average(marks,0))
```

if you really want to do it without numpy

```
averages = [sum(a)/float(len(a)) for a in zip(*marks)] # transpose our marks and average each column
```

Comment: What is numpy as I have never seen this before.

Comment: numpy is a math library that is widely used ... you can do it without numpy pretty easily but its even easier to just use numpy

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to this, but can you please show me how to do this without numpy?

Comment: i put a way to do it without numpy 3 minutes before you asked me to, and 6 minutes before youreiterated that you were prohibited from using numpy for whatever reason

Comment: Sorry about that. I don't understand how simple method works. Can you please dumb this down for me?